# Converting Directx 11 project to work on Windows 8.1 Directx 11.2

Tags: directx, windows-8.1, direct3d, directx-11

I'm trying to run a sample project supplied by Frank Luna (Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11.0).
http://www.d3dcoder.net/d3d11.htm

I'm using Windows 8.1 with the Windows 8 SDK installed - on Visual Studio 2012 (As I read that Windows 8.1 SDK includes direct x 11.2).

Whenever I try to run the project however I get the following build errors:

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dUtil.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\chapter 14 building a first person camera\camera\vertex.h 10  1   Camera
Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dUtil.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\chapter 14 building a first person camera\camera\renderstates.h   10  1   Camera
Error   3   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dUtil.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\chapter 14 building a first person camera\camera\effects.h    11  1   Camera
Error   4   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dApp.h': No such file or directory    c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\chapter 14 building a first person camera\camera\camerademo.cpp   13  1   Camera
Error   5   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xnamath.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\common\waves.h    13  1   Camera
Error   6   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xnamath.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\common\mathhelper.h   11  1   Camera
Error   7   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xnamath.h': No such file or directory   c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\common\lighthelper.h  11  1   Camera
Error   8   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx11.h': No such file or directory    c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\common\d3dutil.h  13  1   Camera
Error   9   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx11.h': No such file or directory    c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\common\d3dutil.h  13  1   Camera
Error   10  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx11.h': No such file or directory    c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\common\d3dutil.h  13  1   Camera
Error   11  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx11.h': No such file or directory    c:\users\ryan willis\desktop\dvd\code\common\d3dutil.h  13  1   Camera
```

After more research it seems that Direct 11.1 onwards changed a lot of things and e.g. "d3dUtil.h" is depreciated.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgalasyn/archive/2013/08/06/notes-on-porting-to-directx-11-1-from-earlier-versions.aspx

Are there any equivilants to 'd3dUtil.h' - I cant find any. 
How can I get this project to run?

Thanks,

Comment: Although the DirectX SDK is now merged into the Windows SDK, some of the components were deprecated along the way.  For more info and suggested alternatives, see [Where's the DirectX SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk.aspx) and the [updated version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/07/01/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2013-edition.aspx) of the same post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirectX never has the d3dUtil.h file, it seems that's a helper class made by Frank Luna, you should double check whether you have include that file in your project.

Comment: Is this the case for 'd3dApp.h' , 'xnamath.h' and 'd3dx11.h' as well? - as after googlings these seem to exist.

Comment: @Ben, d3dApp.h is the case, but xnamath.h and d3dx11.h both come with the DirectX SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest HIGHLY to check out Frank's site

http://www.d3dcoder.net/ 
Mainly his blog post here: http://d3dcoder.net/WordPress/

It covers installing the June 2010 SDK which will give you access to the depreciated DX11 headers.

There are many issues running it on 8.1 and he solves them all there.
I have the same book, followed his setup guide for Windows 8 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

XNA and the D3DX libraries were removed in Windows 8, a lot of projects fail to compile on Windows 8 including the original DirectX 11 SDK sample projects.